# Why does this matrix-based variable have a $\chi^2$ distribution?

Tags: distributions, econometrics, covariance-matrix, chi-squared-distribution

Here is a statement from Greene, Econometric Analysis:

> [image]
>
> Where $H_0$ is the hypothesis that $m:=Rb-q=0$

Where $b$ is a $k$-vector that is normally distributed (i.e. jointly normal elements, not necessarily independent). $R$ and $X$ are $J\times k$ and $n\times k$ deterministic matrices respectively. $q$ is a deterministic $J$-vector.

**Then why does this have the chi squared distribution?**
I think that maybe [Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem) will somehow apply here, but I don't really understand this theorem  when it comes to variables that are not independent.

I know that the sum of squared standard normal variables is $\chi^2$ distributed, but note that the elements of $b$, and therefore certainly the summation of variables that result after the entire matrix operations, are not independent.

**EDIT:**
I just realized: $Var(m|X)^{-1}$ is a $J\times J$ matrix that, because it is the inverse covariance matrix, will I think "cancel out" the dependency between the different values of $m$. So even though the values of $m$ are dependent, the total result can still be seen as a sum of independent squared standard normal variables.  This must be the answer, but I still don't know exactly how to prove it.

Comment: How Many terms do you have in the Sum? How many are dependent?

Comment: Just edited the question. There are $J$ terms in $m$.

Comment: A chi square with J degrees of freedom is, by definition, a Sum of J squared standard normal variables. That follows from the definition of a chi square.

Comment: @fcop, I know. see my question.

Comment: You say that it is a Sum of normal variables, you forgit 'squared'. Why do you say that the m are dependent, what u's m?

Comment: I think your m represent J restrictions on the regression coefficients. The estmators b are normal distributed (gauss markov) so m'm is a Sum of squared normal variables and you divide by the var covar to standardise

Comment: Why do you say that the $m$ are dependent ?